# create a view from a table in sql with selecting unique values

Tags: sql

i want to create a view from a table in sql which has unique values in one column unlike the origin table.
clearly, asume that below table is my origin table:

| product_code | weight |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 0.5 |
| 123 | 0.5 |
| 236 | 1.5 |
| 236 | 1.5 |

i want to have a view which is like to below table:

| product_code | weight |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 0.5 |
| 236 | 1.5 |

what should the sql code be?
any comment is appreciated.

Comment: "which has unique values in one column"? Your sample data shows unique values in *all* columns, for which `SELECT DISTINCT` suffices. If this is about distinct values in only one column and you want to show other columns, too, then you need some kind of aggregation or filtering and rules for this. And you create a view with `CREATE VIEW` obviously.

Comment: What DBMS are you asking this for? Please always tag your SQL requests with the DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
select distinct * from [tblExample]
```

or

```
select distinct product_code, weight from [tblExample]
```